# RAII to Call Function on Destruction?

Tags: c++, boost

If i recall correctly there was a boost implementation of a class where you specify a function and it will call it when the object is destroyed.

```
// it's actually a template if iirc
class Blue
{
public:
    Blue(std::function<void()> f) : func(f) { }
    ~Blue() { func(); }
private:
    std::function<void()> func;
};

// Implementation:

class Foo
{
public:

    Blue Bar()
    {
        /* ... */
        return Blue(std::bind(&Mag, this));
    } 

private:

    void Mag() { /* ... */ }

};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;

    // ...

    {
        foo.Bar();

        // ...

        // Guaranteed Mag() will be called
    }

    // ...

}
```

I forget what boost's implementation is called and was wondering if someone could help me identify it ?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for [`Boost.ScopeExit`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: An arguably more powerful implementation coined `ScopeGuard` can be found at [Change the Way You Write Exception-Safe Code — Forever](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/generic-change-the-way-you-write-excepti/184403758). It, too, can execute an arbitrary function at scope exit, but gives you the ability to dismiss the guard, allowing to write transactional code.

Comment: @Sean Cline
ScopeExit wasn't really what I was thinking, I'll edit my code with some implementation I was thinking of doing.

Comment: so you want `Foo::Mag()` to be invoked when an instance of `Blue` is destroyed, that sounds like `ScopeExit` to me.

Comment: @SamMiller Not really, as Foo has ownership and calls an internal function which is not possible with scope exit.

Comment: Is it possibly [using `shared_ptr` to execute code on block exit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#on_block_exit)?